# Order a list manually C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of ingredients with the name of ingredient and the corresponding values. which I want to sort depending on a pre defined order.

```
 List<Ingredients> frmltnIngredientsList = new List<Ingredients>
```

The list can have as many as 10 records. The first four records should be in the order of:

- Protein
- oil
- Fibre
- Ash

and the rest of them can be in any order

Comment: You cook with ash?! That's new to me! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
frmltnIngredientsList.OrderBy(item =>
   item.Name == "Protein" ? 1 :
   item.Name == "oil" ? 2 :
   item.Name == "Fibre" ? 3 : 
   item.Name == "Ash" ? 4 :
   5);
```

The `OrderBy` call will yield an `IOrderedEnumerable<Ingredient>`. So you need to assign that to a variable,

```
var orderedList = frmltnIngredientsList.OrderBy(item => ...);
```

... or call `ToList()` to be able to assign it to your variable of `List<Ingredient>` type:

```
frmltnIngredientsList = frmltnIngredientsList.OrderBy(item => ...).ToList();
```

It could of course be tidied up a bit. Either you could have a `SortOrder` property on your `Ingredient` list and just run `.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)`, or you could at least move the logic out of sight:

```
public static class IngredientExtensions
{
    public static int GetSortNumber(this Ingredient item) {
       return item.Name == "Protein" ? 1 :
          item.Name == "oil" ? 2 :
          item.Name == "Fibre" ? 3 : 
          item.Name == "Ash" ? 4 : 
          5;
    }
}

...

var orderedList = frmltnIngredientsList.OrderBy(item => item.GetSortNumber());
```

Comment: `OrderBy` doesn't work this way: it uses lazy execution, so it won't do anything until you access your data. Use `frmltnIngredientsList` = `frmltnIngredientsList.OrderBy(item => item.GetSortNumber()).ToList();` instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, I only meant to show how to invoke the method, but I realize now that my code seems to imply that the method alters the source. Will update to avoid further confusion.